# Dial number from iOS app: Cannot convert the expression's type 'Bool' to type 'NSURL!'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to make a call button in an iOS app which prompts the native call pop-up with a number I supply.

This is the code I have at this moment:

```
@IBAction func btnCall(sender : AnyObject) {
    UIApplication .sharedApplication() .openURL(url: "tel://0000000000")
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Cannot convert the expression's type 'Bool' to type 'NSURL!'

Comment: You probably at least want "telprompt://<the number>"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `openURL` method is expecting a `NSURL` object and you are passing a string there. That's why it is not working.

Use the `NSURL` class method:

```
class func URLWithString(_ URLString: String!)
```

#### Example

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url: NSURL(string:"tel:0000000000"))
```

Notice that also the URL schema is `tel:` and not `tel://`.

Comment: `UIApplication .sharedApplication() .openURL(url: NSURL(string:"tel:0000000000"))`, I'd say. I'm not used to Swift yet, but it should be something like that :)

Comment: And the correct schema for phone calls is "tel:000000000".